# The most common commenting marks and mimetypes

Tags: shell-script, mime-types

I'd like to write a shell script to optionally view files without comments (which sometimes take a lot of space so that it becomes difficult to see the lines active in a config file, etc.) and this naturally requires including a number of different commenting marks for different mimetypes. I thought I could easily find it on the Internet, but I couldn't.

I'd appreciate very much if some one can direct me to such a source (or perhaps list several most common ones properly - e.g. `#TEXT` for mimetypes "ABC;DEF;GHI;", `<!--MULTILINETEXT-->` for mimetypes "JKL;MNO", and so on).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler alternative is to view the files with syntax highlighting. This allows you to more easily identify and ignore the comments.

I use [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php):

```bsh
highlight() {
  command highlight -s base16/tomorrow-night -O truecolor "$1" || expand -t4 "$1"
}
cless() {
  highlight "$@" | less
}
```

Note, I'm colourblind, so don't abuse me for my choice of colour style.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I already have a very good text editor (Kate) that features highlighting and I can even customize it to render comments almost invisible. What I need now is something a little more than that. Maybe I can find what I want in one of the source files of this utility. Then I can close this issue. ;-)